# Join 2 files on 2 columns returning 0 for non-matches

Tags: unix, join, awk, merge

I have 2 files, that are sorted, with 3 columns each. I need to merge them based on the first 2 columsn and return 4 columns, being the 2 that are matching and then the 3rd column from each file. I have tried to do in awk using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$3;NEXT}   
  {k=$1FS$2;print k,(a[k]?a[k]:a[k]*1),$3;delete a[k]}        
  END{for(k in a)print k,a[k],"0"}'
```

but it is not working how I hoped.

my input files look like this:

File 1:

> Chr BPPos Chip_1
>
> 1 1234 1
>
> 1 1765 2
>
> 1 2043 3
>
> 2 1231 4

File 2:

> Chr BPPos Chip_2
>
> 1 1765 1
>
> 1 2074 2
>
> 2 1231 3
>
> 2 2141 4

Desired Output:

> Chr BPPos Chip_1 Chip_2
>
> 1 1234 1 0
>
> 1 1765 2 1
>
> 1 2043 3 0
>
> 1 2073 0 2
>
> 2 1231 4 3
>
> 2 2141 0 4

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Steve

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2}
     NR==FNR{a[k]=$3;next}
     k in a{print $0,a[k];delete a[k];next}{print $0,"0"}
     END{for(x in a)print x,"0",a[x]}' file2 file1
```

with your data, output is:

```
kent$  awk '{k=$1 FS $2}NR==FNR{a[k]=$3;next}k in a{print $0,a[k];delete a[k];next}{print $0,"0"}END{for(x in a)print x,"0",a[x]}' f2 f1
Chr BPPos Chip_1 Chip_2
1 1234 1 0
1 1765 2 1
1 2043 3 0
2 1231 4 3
1 2074 0 2
2 2141 0 4
```

Comment: This seems to give me a weird format at the top of the file, my header is incorrect, and for some reason the first column and last column seem to have joined. Maybe my data is not quite right, I will do some editing and try again, but the below comment seems to work, however is much slower. Thank you for your help here, I feel like my application of your solution probably does not do it justice.

Comment: @slarmer1  I did the test with the two examples you provided, and the output, as you can see, was posted with the answer. If you have data format other than the file1 file2 in your question, the output could be different. Anyway, in question you have shown your codes, I think you should know awk programming. You can read my codes, understand the idea, do corresponding changes to fit your data.

Comment: I think I've got it sorted now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ k = $1 FS $2 } !a[k]++ { keys[i++] = k } FNR == NR { b[k] = $3; next } { c[k] = $3 } END { for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) { k = keys[i]; print k, k in b ? b[k] : "0", k in c ? c[k] : "0" } }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Chr BPPos Chip_1 Chip_2
1 1234 1 0
1 1765 2 1
1 2043 3 0
2 1231 4 3
1 2074 0 2
2 2141 0 4
```

Comment: This worked beautifully I think, the file is massive, so it will take a while to check and make sure, but I think this did the trick. Thank You!!!